# Original install date from registry

Tags: c#

I've been trying to modify a code I found on here a couple of years ago to pull the original OS Install date from the registry and have it display in a .txt field within an application.  This is the code I have:

```
public static DateTime GetWindowsInstallationDateTime(string scomputer)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, scomputer);

        key = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", false);
        if (key != null)
        {
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            object objValue = key.GetValue("InstallDate");
            string stringValue = objValue.ToString();
            Int64 regVal = Convert.ToInt64(stringValue);

            DateTime installDate = startDate.AddSeconds(regVal);

            return installDate;
        }

        return DateTime.MinValue;

    }
```

and then I call the information into the text field using the following variable and assignment:

```
string scomputer = System.Environment.MachineName;

osOriginalInstall.text = GetWindowsInstallationDateTime(scomputer).ToString();
```

Unfortunately the only return result I get is the base 1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM.  I confirmed I do have access to the D-WORD information in the registry but UAC does make me authenticate with an ADMIN account when trying to access the registry within our Environment.  I tried launching my application as ADMIN but still gives the same result.

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this typo - *UAC does make me authenticate..*? It does or not?

Comment: In our environment, to access the registry, I do have to authenticate with my admin account via UAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
var key = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, 
    scomputer);
```

to

```
var key = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, 
    scomputer, 
    RegistryView.Registry64);
```

I think this value is only available from the 64-bit hive.  Tested successfully (locally) using:

```
var key = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);

key = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", false);
if (key != null)
{
    DateTime startDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    object objValue = key.GetValue("InstallDate");
    string stringValue = objValue.ToString();
    Int64 regVal = Convert.ToInt64(stringValue);

    DateTime installDate = startDate.AddSeconds(regVal);
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :o)   If you don't mind, could you accept this as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

and if hours diffrent;

change this:

```
    var key = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);

key = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", false);
if (key != null)
{
    DateTime startDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    object objValue = key.GetValue("InstallDate");
    string stringValue = objValue.ToString();
    Int64 regVal = Convert.ToInt64(stringValue);

    DateTime installDate = startDate.AddSeconds(regVal);
}
```

with this:

```
var key = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);

key = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", false);
if (key != null)
{
    DateTime startDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    object objValue = key.GetValue("InstallDate");
    string stringValue = objValue.ToString();
    Int64 regVal = Convert.ToInt64(stringValue);

    DateTime installDate = startDate.AddSeconds(regVal).ToLocalTime();//LocalTime
}
```